# Throw exception in switch statement

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement

This program is something simplified to what we would find in a music store. We enter the comand we want and it makes what that comand supposes to do. These are the options.

- Create "**client**"|"**music**"|"**selling**"
- List "**client**"|"**music**"|"**selling**"
- Erase "**client**"|"**music**"|"**selling**" (using, or without using a code that is generated when we create new statement)

The program must execute until we type "close".

Here I'm posting what I've done until now.

The main question is how to throw a exception if we type wrong a comand or we type something that doesn't exist here. Now, wen this occurs it just goes back to the begining. I would apreciate too if you give me advices on any change or modification that you think could be better for the program, I'm just starting with this and I know this could be done in a better way:

```
public class Main {

    static GestionarMusica musiclist= new GestionarMusica(20);
    static GestionarCliente clientlist= new GestionarCliente(20);

    static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    static String instructions;

    public static void main (String[] args){

    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for instructions: ");
            instructions= input.nextLine();

            switch (instructions){
                case "create client":
                    createClient();
                    break;
                case "create music":
                    createMusic();
                    break;
                case "create selling":
                    //createSelling();
                    break;

                case "list client":
                    listClient();
                    break;
                case "list music":
                    listMusic();
                    break;
                case "list selling":
                    //listSelling();
                    break;
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException npe){
            System.out.println("There are not articles on the list");
        }

        if (instructions.equals("erase client")){
            eraseClientWithoutCode();
        }
        if (instructions.length() <= 18 && instructions.length() >= 17 && instructions.substring(0, 16).equals("erase client")){
            String client_code = instructions.substring(16);
            client_code = client_code.trim();
            int code = Integer.parseInt(client_code);
            eraseClientWithCode(code);
        }

        if (instruction.equals("erase music")){
            eraseMusicWithoutCode();
        }
        if (instructions.length() <= 17 && instructions.length() >= 16 && instructions.substring(0, 15).equals("erase music")){
            String music_code = instructions.substring(15);
            music_code = music_code.trim();
            int code = Integer.parseInt(music_code);
            eraseMusicWithCode(code);
        }

        if (instructions.equals("erase selling")){
            eraseSellingWithoutCode();
        }
        if (instructions.length() <= 16 && instructions.length() >= 15 && instructions.substring(0, 14).equals("erase selling")){
            String selling_code = instructions.substring(14);
            selling_code = selling_code.trim();
            int code = Integer.parseInt(selling_code);
            eraseSellingWithCode(code);
        }

    }while(!instructions.equals("close"));
}


public static void createMusic() {
    System.out.println("Insert album title: ");
    String title = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Insert album autor: ");
    String autor = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Insert format: ");
    String format = input.nextLine();

    musiclist.add(new Music(title, autor, format, musiclist.generateCode()));
}

public static void listMusic() {
    System.out.println(musiclist.toString());
}

public static void eraseMusicWithCode(int code) {
    musiclist.delete(code);
    System.out.println("Article deleted");
}

public static void eraseMusicWithoutCode() {
    System.out.println("Insert article code: ");
    int code = input.nextInt();
    musiclist.delete(code);
    System.out.println("Article deleted");
}
```

**UPDATE-- About the use of default in the switch statement**

I cannot use the default because this reason. Inside the switch I have the **create** and **list** commands, but I have had to set the **erase** commands outside the witch because these depends on if I enter the command with the code, or without it. So, if I enter an erase command and if I have the default inside the switch, it will show the exception.

Comment: in switch, use default: \\ throw an exception.

Comment: To throw a exception in a switch statement you throw the exception.  The only slight surprise is that if the case only throws an exception -- no `if` logic -- then the `break` will be dead if you use it and the compiler will complain.  So skip the `break`.

Comment: Post updated about the use of the default command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `switch/case` add `default` for handling unknown commands. You don't need any exception for this. Just handle wrong input properly.
So you will have to preparse input and determine if those are cases with three arguments. Move the code for special cases inside `switch/case` and check 3rd parameter. I make it for one case so you can get idea.
So with default, a bit dirty, **not tested** code will be:

```
    public static void main (String[] args){

    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for instructions: ");
            instructions= input.nextLine();
        String preparsedInstructions = instructions;
        int from = instructions.indexOf(" ");
        if(from > -1){
            int to = preparsedInstructions.indexOf(" ", from + 1);
            if(to > -1){
                preparsedInstructions = preparsedInstructions.substring(0, to);
            }
        }

            switch (preparsedInstructions){
                case "create client":
                    createClient();
                    break;
                case "create music":
                    createMusic();
                    break;
                case "create selling":
                    //createSelling();
                    break;

                case "list client":
                    listClient();
                    break;
                case "list music":
                    listMusic();
                    break;
                case "list selling":
                    //listSelling();
                    break;
                case "erase client":
            if (instructions.length() <= 18 && instructions.length() >= 17 && instructions.substring(0, 16).equals("erase client")){
                String client_code = instructions.substring(16);
                client_code = client_code.trim();
                int code = Integer.parseInt(client_code);
                eraseClientWithCode(code);
            }else{
                    eraseClientWithoutCode();
            }
                    break;
        ...//do for erase music,selling

        default: //error handling
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException npe){
            System.out.println("There are not articles on the list");
        }



    }while(!instructions.equals("close"));
}
```

Comment: I'll try it now, just one thing... in this line `preparsedInstructions = ss1.substring(0, to);`, what variable is `ss1`?

Answer (score 1):

Just to simplify

```
        case "list selling":
                //listSelling();
                break;

        default:
            if(instructions.equals("erase music") || instructions.equals("erase client") ){
                System.out.println("hello delete");
                //do your operation
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("hello default throw exceliotn");
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid entry");

            }
        }
```

You may effectively move the `if` clause in to a method and you can return 'boolean flag' to determine to throw exception or not . This will increase the readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can add  a `default:` case in which you handle something else being input. The statement in `default:` is  executed if the value if not any of the listed options. I believe [switch's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) shows well how to do that.